# Can a non-idempotent function converge to itself under repeated self-application?

Tags: limits, functions

$f : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$

$f \circ f \neq f$, non-idempotency

$\lim_{n \to \infty} \underbrace{f \circ \dots \circ f}_\text{n times} = f$, convergence to self under self-application.

Can such a function exist? How would I even prove such a function exists if it can?

I've considered functions like $\lim_{c\to \infty} f_c(x) = \begin{cases}x + 1, & x < c \\ x - c, & x \ge c\end{cases}$ which has a cycle of length $c$ before taking the limit as $c$ goes to infinity. The problem is that I'm fairly certain such a function would approach $f(x) = x + 1$. Under self-application, it just diverges to $f(x) = \infty$

Comment: Is this function supposed to be continuous?

Comment: @IgorRivin It would be really easy to show that continuity wasn't possible if I restricted myself to continuous functions. I imagine that any function that satisfies the all three conditions would have to be speckled across the real plane like a staticy fuzz. Intuitively, I know that such a function would not be in any way nice.

Comment: This certainly won't work for continuous function, as a simple limit can show. If a continuous $f$ converges in this sense to some $g$, then we must have $f\circ g=g\circ f=g$.

Comment: It may be prudent to consider $\Bbb Q$-linear maps.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom How would I research that? Rational-linear maps? Q-linear maps? I'm not sure I'm finding the right things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no such function. Consider a point $a$ and its forward orbit $(a, b, c, \dotsc).$ By assumption, the limit of this sequence is $b.$ But the forward orbit of $b$ is $(b, c, \dotsc) $ and since the limit of this orbit is the same as that of the first one, it is equal to $b$ also, and thus $c = f(b) = b.$ So, the function is idempotent.

Comment: Elegant proof. I was trying an argument on the same lines, but you put it down very nicely (and faster). +1

Comment: @DanielRobert-Nicoud Thanks!